# Explicitly tell to CMake target_link_libraries() to read dependency as target and not as a file from system path?

Tags: cmake

I got multiple warnings:

```
CMake Warning at libsysev/src/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_library):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target sysev because files
  in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libzlog.so] in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf may be hidden by files in:
      /home/user/project/BUILD/libzlog/src

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

Target defined as following:

```
add_library(sysev SHARED main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sysev PUBLIC zlog)
```

`zlog` provided in source code and also installed to the system.
Root `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
project(xxx)
add_subdirectory(zlog)
add_subdirectory(sysev)
```

I want to disambiguate zlog. CMake must know this is a target and not a file from system path.

Comment: "CMake must know this is a target and not a file from system path." - CMake always **prefers a target variant** to a non-target one. CMake even **defers** the resolution of the string until the end of the whole configuration process for check whether target will be created. It seems there is no `zlog` **target** in your case...

Comment: you are right, i forgot to clean cache

Comment: If you move this test to answer I'll accept

Comment: You can also use `if(NOT TARGET targetname)` to test if target is already defined.